# Java upload file (image specifically) from a JApplet to MS MVC page

Tags: java, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, applet, jnlp

I am going mad trying to find an example of file upload code in Java that will enable me to submit (POST) images to a URL from a JApplet in the same manner that an html form would post a multipart form. I have found loads of examples referencing servlets, jsp, apache but this is no good to me as my applet is being displayed in a Microsoft MVC 2 .Net project on IIS 7

Surely there has to be a simple way to do this - I am using jnlp/webstart and have no issues accessing the files I want to upload I just can't seem to find a simple sample to get me underway.

Any feedback/tutes greatly appreciated, I am happy to be pointed in the right direction in regards to the appropriate Java classes/methods - this will at least give me a starting point.

Cheers
Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it got the better of me and starting googling again but this time for Java Submit Form rather than Java File Upload and I found this great class that I have just confirmed works correctly with great abstraction of the painful intricacies of this process.

http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/17679/1954

Answer (score 0):

Short Pointer: Use `URL`, `URLConnection`, `setDoOutput()`, and `getOutputStream()`.